# Tableview.reloadData doesn't work

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, segue

I have two controllers and I'd like to pass datas between them:
This is the first controller, a tableviewcontroller.

```
class BooksVC: UITableViewController {

var books: [String] = []


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.title = "Books"

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return books.count
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = books[indexPath.row] 

    return cell
}
}
```

And this is the second controller, a viewcontroller

```
class AddController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var inputField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

@IBAction func done(_ sender: Any) {
    let myVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BooksVC") as! BooksVC
    myVC.books.append(inputField.text!)
    myVC.tableView.reloadData()

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

Reloaddata doesn't work, can you help me I would be very glad.

Comment: You create a new view controller object with `instantiateViewController` but you don't do anything to display it.  Do you already have a different `BooksVC` that you should be using?

Comment: No, I have to connect to the BooksVC controller, not create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a reference to the first view controller to do what you need. 
You can do something like this:

```
class AddController: UIViewController {
....
weak var booksVC: BooksVC?

@IBAction func done(_ sender: Any) {
    booksVC.books.append(inputField.text!)
    booksVC.tableView.reloadData()

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

}
```

And when you instatiate an AddController, you need to pass a reference of your BooksVC. Something like this:

```
addController.booksVC = self
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright for second ViewController when doneButton pressed you can
   dissmisstheview 
    trasffer data
    self.parentviewController. books.apped(inputField.text!)
    self.dissmissviewcontroller

than in the first VC you can do something like this

```
in viewWillAppear func{
tableview.reloadData()
}
```